# Edgware.Release CANNOT configure the zuul time out by hystrix.command.default but [serviceId]

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-netflix

```
hystrix:
  command:
    default:
      execution:
        timeout:
          enabled: true
        isolation:
          thread:
            timeoutInMilliseconds: 30000
```

This property does not work until I replace 'default' with my serviceId.
I just saw the doc of ***Edgware.Release*** configure the zuul timeout using default for the commandKey.

More Info, I find the hytrix command is **RibbonCommand** when I debug in my program, and The commandKey is always equal my serviceId. And I find no where to change it in the spring cloud doc.

And This is my application.yml

```
server:
  port: 80
spring:
  application:
    name: mofeng-pay-zuul
  ##zipkin:
  ##  base-url: http://localhost:7000
  ##sleuth:
  ##  sampler:
  ##    percentage: 1.0
eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka/

logging:
  level:
    com:
      DEBUG
  file: ${JAVA_LOG_HOME}/zuul.log

zuul:
  ribbonIsolationStrategy: THREAD
  threadPool:
    useSeparateThreadPools: true
  host:
    connections: 500
    socket-timeout-millis: 30000
    connect-timeout-millis: 30000

ribbon:
  ReadTimeout: 10000
  ConnectTimeout: 10000
  MaxAutoRetries: 1
  MaxAutoRetriesNextServer: 1
  eureka:
    enabled: true
  eager-load:
    enabled: true
    clients: 
    - client-service


hystrix:
  command:
    client-service:
      execution:
        timeout:
          enabled: true
        isolation:
          thread:
            timeoutInMilliseconds: 30000
```

Removing the hystrix configuration and appending the config as follows:

```
client-service:
  ribbon:
    ConnectTimeout: 10000
    ReadTimeout: 30000
    MaxTotalHttpConnections: 500
    MaxConnectionsPerHost: 100
```

It still does not work.

Answer (score 1):

It is a bug (actually an improvement) that was changed in ***Edgware.SR1***.

https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/pull/2633

In ***Edgware.RELEASE***, you can not use Hystrix timeout with `default` key because timeout is set in the code with Ribbon connection timeout plus read timeout. The only way to set timeout in Edgware.RELEASE is setting timeout with command key (service id).

But it was changed. Please try to use ***Edgware.SR1*** or later.